# KSH on old unix systemV: search history

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ksh, command-history, svr4

I have set a good ksh environement on old unix

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/acct:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/ucb
export PATH
EDITOR=vi
FCEDIT=vi
export EDITOR
export FCEDIT
HOSTNAME=`uname -n`
HISTSIZE=500
LOGNAME=myname
TERM=386AT
PS1="\$LOGNAME@\$HOSTNAME:\$PWD\$ "
set -o emacs
stty 38400 intr ^C kill ^U tabs ixon ixoff ixany
setcolor white black 
alias type="whence -v"
alias __A=`echo "\020"`     # up arrow = ^p = back a command
alias __B=`echo "\016"`     # down arrow = ^n = down a command
alias __C=`echo "\006"`     # right arrow = ^f = forward a character
alias __D=`echo "\002"`     # left arrow = ^b = back a charactoe
alias __H=`echo "\001"`     # home = ^a = start of line
alias __Y=`echo "\005"`     # end = ^e = end of line
```

With this i have search history with arrows,etc,my question is: is possible to make an alias for ctrl+r search history?Old ksh support search history?
I'm on unix svr4 ATT

Comment: Ctrl-R in emacs mode ought to just work. It is not an incremental character-by-character search like in bash. You have to type Ctrl-R, then the string you want to search for, then the enter key. If this doesn't work, please type Ctrl-V and tell us the version that it displays.

Comment: It works,thanks add as answer so i can select as solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search backward in your ksh command history, <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd> in emacs mode ought to work, even if you're running an old version such as ksh88. It is not an incremental character-by-character search like in bash. You have to type <kbd>Ctrl-R</kbd>, then the string you want to search for, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.